# Even distribution of numbers in array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

My problem is that I have a given array of n numbers between 1 and 100. The goal is to pick 5 numbers which result in a minimum total distance. The total distance is calculated by summing up the distance of each number in the initial array to the closest of the 5 picked numbers.

What I (sort of) tried and thought about:

- Taking the average number of the array and dividing it by 5 to get something useful?
- Dividing the array length by 5, that numbers x and then the first number is array[x] the second one is array[x*2] and so on

Example

- Input [5, 10, 15, 20, ..., 85, 90, 95, 100]
- Output [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]
  (There might be a better output but I hope this makes the goal clear)

As you can see I'm pretty lost and just can't come up with a solution. There probably is a super easy solution to this that I just don't get.

I am just looking for a hint not a solution, I wan't to figure that out myself.

Comment: Which language is this supposed to be in?

Comment: Are the inputs always evenly distributed from each other, as in your example?

Comment: This is k-medians clustering in one dimension. I don't think the classical expectation maximization algorithm is exact in all cases, but it's possible to write a dynamic program.

Comment: what do you mean when you say `the distance of each number in the initial array`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No they are random and can contain duplicates

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Lets say you have an input like in the example. For the numbers 5, 10 and 15 the closest picked number is 10. Therefore the distance is 5 , 0 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that works in polynomial time.

First, sort your array of `n` things.  Next, calculate a 2-dim array which for every `0 <= i <= j < n` contains the index of the optimal element to fill the range from the `i`th element to the `j`th element.  Fill out a similar array of the total distance for each interval from that optimal array.

As an example with the above sample output, the first 2-dim array could look like:

```
optimal_index = [
    [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9],
    [ 1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10],
    [ 2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10],
    [ 3,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11],
    [ 4,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11],
    [ 5,  5,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12],
    [ 6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12],
    [ 7,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13],
    [ 8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13],
    [ 9,  9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14],
    [10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14],
    [11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15],
    [12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15],
    [13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16],
    [14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16],
    [15, 15, 16, 16, 17],
    [16, 16, 17, 17],
    [17, 17, 18],
    [18, 18],
    [19],
]
```

where the index of the optimal element for the range from `i` to `j` is at `optimal_index[i][j-i]`.  With the same indexing scheme, the cost matrix would be:

```
optimal_cost = [
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245, 280, 320, 360, 405, 450, 500],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245, 280, 320, 360, 405, 450],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245, 280, 320, 360, 405],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245, 280, 320, 360],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245, 280, 320],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245, 280],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210, 245],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180, 210],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 180],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100, 125],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 80],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45, 60],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 45],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20, 30],
    [ 0, 5, 10, 20],
    [ 0, 5, 10],
    [ 0, 5],
    [ 0],
]
```

Now what about if we fill ranges with 2 elements?  This is a question of taking each range, and looking the costs at each point we could divide it.  That new data structure just needs to contain the places to separate between "closest to first element" and "closest to second".  From this division we can take any range and quickly divide it into the optimal 2, then tell you what the two selected elements are, and the total cost.  This can be filled in with a similar matrix.  Note that the previous `optimal_cost` matrix will make these calculations very straightforward.

Next, what about ranges with 4 elements?  This is exactly the same as ranges of 2 elements, **except** that we are now dividing between the first pair and the second pair.  But the logic is the same.

And finally, what about our problem with 5 elements?  That's just a question of calculating the optimal division between closest to the first 4 elements and closest to the last one.  So just try all of the possibilities.

The natural generalization of this to filling `k` things in an array of size `n` is `O(n^3 log(k))`.

Comment: Could you give an example for the first step as to what that array is supposed to look like?

Comment: @Nicolas I added data structures.  Due to the symmetry of the input, the matrices are very structured.  With random numbers, they wouldn't be so much.